# Is there a better way to do this (max-width)?

Tags: css

On the site I am working on, I have some elements that I want the `background` to fill the entire width of the browser, but I also want there to be a `max-width` on the elements.

I can accomplish this, but I feel like maybe there is a 'better' to do it than I am currently.

Here is the fiddle with a raw example: http://jsfiddle.net/5KJf5/

As you can in the fiddle, the class `max_w` is solely there to put the `max-width` on the element; if I put `max-width` on the `.row` class, at the `max-width` the `background-color` will stop.

So, my question is this:

Is there a better way to have an element's `background-color` span the whole screen while still being able to maintain a `max-width`, other than creating a special class just to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of what you would like it to look like?

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/5KJf5/2/

Comment: for just colors, you can use background  multiple gradient or image or a mixed of both.

Comment: I think the way you did is ok.

Comment: i mean this for gradient : http://jsfiddle.net/5KJf5/3/ :) or http://jsfiddle.net/5KJf5/4/ no matter how much content

Comment: The way I would like it to look would be how it looks in the fiddle I made; I was just wondering if there was a better way than adding a new class just for setting `max-width`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no direct way to expand the background outside the actual area of an element. To achieve **what you really want**, we can use relative `padding` with the help of `calc()` function, we also have to set the `box-sizing` to `border-box` so that the container's size includes the borders (not the content by default):

```
.row {
   ...
   padding: 10px calc((100% - 300px)/2);
   box-sizing:border-box;    
}
```

Now you don't need the wrapper `max_w`, here is the [fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5KJf5/6/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use :before for that background.

```
.row:before{
    content:'';
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    background-color:aqua;
    top:0;
    left:0;
 }
```

My example : http://jsfiddle.net/5KJf5/5/